# What is the difference between USB On-The-Go (OTG) and USB Host Mode?

Tags: usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go

What is the difference between USB On-The-Go (OTG) and USB Host Mode?

They seem to be more or less the same. *Are they?*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the context of Android devices, the terms are often used interchangeably.

## Host mode

USB has two different kinds of endpoint (connected device), like a client-server interface. One device is the computer (or *host*), and it's in charge: it's the server. All the other devices (the *peripherals*) are the clients, and can only communicate with the server. Usually, a device can only act in one of those two rôles: it wouldn't make sense for (say) a keyboard to be the host. That's the way the protocol works, and the connectors are designed to make that easier for users: hosts have the rectangular A connector, and peripherals have either the square B connector or a mini- or micro- version.

*Host mode* is a name for when a device is acting as a host. Every USB connection has exactly one device in *host mode*. PCs always run in host mode. (You wouldn't usually call it that for a PC, because it's not really a "mode", it's always like that.)

## USB-OTG

A phone is a bit different, though. Sometimes you want it to act as a peripheral: for example, so you can plug it into a PC, so the PC can access the phone's storage. Sometimes you want it to act as a host: for example, to connect a physical keyboard or mouse to it. This is why many Android devices now support USB host mode as well as USB peripheral mode: they can act in either rôle. But how can you make this work, when a host's USB socket is different from a peripheral's?

This is where *USB-on-the-go* (OTG) comes in. It adds an extra pin to the micro-USB socket. If you plug a normal A-to-B USB cable, the device acts in peripheral mode. If you connect a special USB-OTG cable, it has the pin connected at one end, and the device at that end acts in host mode.

This can be a little confusing if one cable has seemingly identical plugs at either end, which do different things. But cables with USB-OTG at both ends are uncommon: it's more common to use an adaptor, which has a host-mode USB-OTG plug at one end, and a rectangular USB-A socket on the other. You can plug a normal USB cable into this adaptor, and it will work normally.

## Conclusion

The names refer to two different parts of the USB technology, but they're very similar. After all, if a device "supports USB-OTG," it must support acting in "host mode". The converse is often the case, but not always. Most Android devices that support host mode do so via USB-OTG, but there are a few counterexamples: the original Asus Eee Pad Transformer, for example, has USB-A sockets in its keyboard, allowing it to act in host mode without a USB-OTG cable. And of course PCs support host mode without USB-OTG.

So although the terms are usually used to mean the same thing in the Android world - can I plug a USB stick into my phone? - and for most devices it makes no difference which you're talking about, there is a distinction.

Comment: Don't forget the power.... OTG requires a y-split cable for those that require external power - perhaps for a device that requires stronger power...Also USB peripheral did come into presence until after Honeycomb which introduced it.

Comment: @t0mm13b Actually it's entirely possible to supply power to connected devices via USB-OTG, just as with normal USB. It's just that most phones won't supply enough power for high-current devices like hard disks: but that's to do with the specific device, regardless of whether USB-OTG or normal USB is used.

Comment: @t0mm13b I'm not sure what you mean by "USB peripheral did come into presence until after Honeycomb which introduced it." Android has always supported acting as a USB peripheral.

Comment: No, it required a custom kernel - and it was iffy support depending on the chipset, it was in Honeycomb API that the USB support came into being and became more popular in ICS upwards

Comment: @t0mm13b *Peripheral* means, for example, being a USB mass storage device that you can plug into a PC. I think you're confusing that with *host* support, which was added in Honeycomb.

Comment: @Dan Hulme: So what does it mean when USB Host is mentioned in the specifications of a device, but there is no USB OTG? for example in Galaxy Note II.

Comment: @Omne If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the **Ask Question** button.

Comment: @Dan Hulme: I don't think it is a different question, thanks anyway.