# Does LG Optimus G (E-0975) support USB host mode?

Tags: usb-host-mode

Device: LG optimus G (E-0975)
Android: 4.1.2

Does LG Optimus G (E-0975) support USB host mode?

If yes, what can I do with that? How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [USB Host Diagnostics](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=optimus%20g), NO.

**Related Post:**

- [How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support)
- [What is the difference between USB On-The-Go (OTG) and USB Host Mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51035/what-is-the-difference-between-usb-on-the-go-otg-and-usb-host-mode)

Answer (score -2):

no it doesnt...and you cant enable it because the battery is too low and it should be able to provide the usb with 5V and its not...so sadly there is now way to enable it