# Can I attach a USB mic to any Android phone?

Tags: usb, video, audio-recording

Can I attach a USB mic to any Android phone?  Which one?

I am asking since I need to be able to shoot video with sound clear of noise.

Hence, I need the phone to shoot good video quality as well(full HD at least).

Comment: Never tried with an USB mike – but using one via the "headset plug" should do, as that's what headsets use as well.

Comment: You mean the 3.5mm audio jack, right?

Comment: Exactly. I just had a black-out concerning the term, sorry.

Comment: Np, it was clear but I needed to be 100% sure:)

Comment: I've summed it up with additional details in my answer below, for your convenience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android currently doesn't support USB Audio Paths. You can use USB Audio if you have a Nexus 5 with Android L Preview. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [Android supports standard USB audio class devices](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb.html):

> Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above supports a subset of USB audio
>   class 1 (UAC1) features:
>
> - The Android device must act as host
> - The audio format must be PCM (interface type I)
> - The bit depth must be 16-bits, 24-bits, or 32-bits where 24 bits of useful audio data are left-justified within the most significant
>     bits of the 32-bit word
> - The sample rate must be either 48, 44.1, 32, 24, 22.05, 16, 12, 11.025, or 8 kHz
>     The channel count must be 1 (mono) or 2 (stereo)

Also, Android 3.1 or higher can support USB audio [if you buy an app from eXtream Software](http://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/2015-07-22-12-01-14/usb-audio-driver), which bundles its own drivers.

Also, your hardware has to support [USB Host mode (USB On-The-Go)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51035/693).  There are apps to test whether it does:

[How can I determine if my device has USB Host Mode (OTG) support?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36887/693)

Comment: I tested this and it works (Samsung S6, Yeti Blue USB Mic)

Answer (score 2):

If you need an external microphone, and your device does not support USB audio (as [Hiemanshu's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/78909/16575) suggests): A work-around would be using a microphone with the 3.5" audio jack. As headsets use that successfully, it should work.

I've never tried, so theoretically a side-effect could be sound output gets blocked whith the device assuming you've got a headset plugged in. If that's the case, there are apps available to control where which audio is routed to. You can find some in [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=83#group_330).