# Connect a USB soundcard to an Android phone? And use it for videos?

Tags: usb, audio, video, usb-on-the-go

Is it possible to connect a **USB soundcard** to an Android phone, with an USB OTG cable?

[image: OTG cable]

... and then use this USB soundcards's stereo input as audio when making a video with the phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I attach a USB mic to any Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78904/can-i-attach-a-usb-mic-to-any-android-phone)

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is possible.
I'm doing this with several devices for amateur radio and video production with KineMaster Pro.
For amateur radio, I use the DigiMaster MiniProSC connected via OTG cable to a Nexus 9 via OTG cable. I also do this with SignaLink usb connected the same way. Both of these devices have internal usb sound cards with audio in, audio out, and usb connection between android tablet and the radio.

For YouTube videos, I use KineMaster Pro with Zoom H2 and H4 as external microphone or line in. Both connected via USB to the Nexus 9, and both work perfectly!

I know this is an old thread, but when I saw the answer from the guy who says it doesn't work, I wanted to correct this out-of-date information, letting everyone who makes there way here via Google search of the correct answer!

Btw, it also works on Samsung galaxy s4 i9506. I've tested on Android 5, 6 and 7 successfully.

Thanks

Comment: I also have a Zoom H2. Do you connect it to your phone with an OTG cable?

Answer (score 2):

Android DOES support USB sound cards over android 5.0, or, if you have a sony, the Z series (Z2 and up), they support it since 4.4. I use my phone with a cheap chinese device, but tried a Xonar U3, and a creative Play!.
However I never tried the audio recording through these cards.

Comment: Which app to use to record from these audio interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

I use a Cambridge Audio DAC Magic XS with my Nexus 5 running Marshmallow and it works fine. I have also tried a Behringer 8 channel desk that has usb audio interface, and it seems to work as well.

Comment: Could you link to the products please, if possible?

Comment: Which app do you use to record using this DAC @kikermo?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is (mostly) possible.

1. You need to be **connected via USB OTG** (which you are) that your phone acts as a host and not as a peripheral device
2. The **audio interface** / sound card **must be [*class compliant*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_driver)** (see also [here](https://m-audio.com/kb/article/1706))

Many (including **some** interfaces from RME, Focusrite, Behringer, M-Audio,  ...) but not all audio interfaces are class compliant.

Many phones nowadays don't come with a headphone jack. Those USB adapters or USB headphones are in turn a small sound card.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but extreamsd's [USB Audio Recorder PRO](http://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/products/usb-audio-recorder-pro) seems to do what you want. There is a demo version.

Answer (score 0):

working with zoom h6 + samsung A6 + opencamera app .
im getting some micro click from time to time though. gonna try with with other app and power the zoom externally.

Answer (score -1):

No. Android doesn't support drivers for these types of devices. Its support for external devices is pretty limited to simple input devices, such as keyboards and mice, and storage devices, along with occasional special peripherals that your individual app would be designed to use. A PC sound card is way outside of its functionality.

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard, actually. If you use something like this ( http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Position-Headset-Splitter-Adapter/dp/B00CPEZ4J6 ), you can split the headset jack into separate jacks, one dedicated to audio out (speakers, headphones), and one dedicated to audio in (microphone). Assuming whatever app you're recording with is capable of pulling from the headset instead of the built-in speakers (I'd recommend testing with a cheap wired headset before investing), then you can adapt your line-out to 3.5mm, and boom, you're golden.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's something that I don't think an Android device is going to be able to do for you. At least not anything normal. With the upcoming additional functionality that USB-C is going to allow for with new devices, and the more advanced audio profiles, we might eventually see professional audio mixing equipment for them. Android M is supposed to severely up the support for audio functionality, including MIDI, which may finally bring it in line with iOS which does do a lot of this. I think right now you're stuck with mono.

Comment: Android has supported USB audio since 5.0, and Exstream app supports it for Android 3.1 or higher.  I don't know of a way to connect it to built-in video app though.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. @TurboFool please remove..