# USB C hub and charging at the same time

Tags: charging, usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go

I bought a USB C hub with charging integrated but as soon as I plug in the charging cable to the hub the other ports stop working and the phone only charges. The USB ports and Ethernet ports stop working while the hub gets external power.

Does anybody have a solution or know about a hub that works both for charging and OTG on Android 11 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can OTG HUB charge with connected charger more than 0.5A?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220032/can-otg-hub-charge-with-connected-charger-more-than-0-5a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simultaneous USB-OTG and charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157856/simultaneous-usb-otg-and-charging)

Comment: Those threads are pretty old and don't tackle exactly the same problem. My device does charge and more than 0.5A when plugged and the second guy built a custom device. I'm using a newer phone/os and not a custom cable. I'm looking for someone with recent experience with the subject.

Comment: Using an USB-c port for charging (power input) and data (port used as USB master) at the same time is possible but as far as I know it has not been implemented for smartphones. On PC notebooks this is nothing unusual but on a smartphone it seems to be complicated. Not sure if this is a technical limitation or just nobody ever implemented it.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Furthermore, I've heard of people doing it, it should be possible with some kernel tweaking and/or root.

Comment: i am using otg charge hub to power usb-c ethernet in order to save battery, but no phone or tablet is charged. i have compiled kernel and can edit source code, i am very interested in solution too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seams that my issue was One Plus's Oxygen OS didn't support this feature. I installed a few kernels hoping that one would fix it and it did. The kernel is called Dora based on nem0.

Comment: I edited would you mind sharing where I can find the stuff necessary to ad this functionality.

Comment: that one? will have a look next days thx
https://github.com/nem0-z/dora_kernel_oneplus_sm8150

Comment: yes this is the one

Comment: I've seen looking for days! What OnePlus did you use and which OS did you install with this kernel? Any ideas if this particular one should work on a OnePlus 3T?

Comment: I was beginning to think that this maybe was a hardware limitation or the OP3 since I've tried 5 different USB OTG cables/splitters