# Android with USB C Hub and charging not working

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I would like to have my Android device (Alldocube iPlay 7T) to be charged and simultaneously have a few USB devices connected.
Note - I'm new to Android - but needed this setup for a specific purpose.

I purchased a USB C hub with power through, it charges the device but the hub doesn't work. It's verified to work on PC/Mac.
Then i read that an OTG adapter is required for USB Hubs, so got one (USB C to USB 3) and I can connect an FTDI based serial port to the OTG adapter and a flash drive - but this doesn't work through a USB hub, powered or not (belkin) - these are also verified to work on PC/Mac.
I read about a guy in this forum that seems to have it working but he needed to update the OS, but he's hardware setup wasn't described.

Can anyone share what hardware setup and software setup is required? Is it required to brick the device and update the android version? (currently installed 9, kernel version  4.4.147)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB C hub and charging at the same time](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237441/usb-c-hub-and-charging-at-the-same-time)

Comment: You need a custom wired you can find several instruction to do so on line !

Comment: @alecxs - thx for your comment - i did read that post, catfoxes didn't mention he's hardware setup. Also it indicated that you need to root your phone and install another android version. I was hoping that i didn't have to root the device (i'm new to android). I have seen a youtube video of an LG V30 where it seems PnP - even without OTG adapter. So wondering what the best (easiest) solution is to get it to work...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1eEf.jpg